# How can i add a date function in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel

Hi please tell me how can I add a date function in `laravel 5.5` and how to set the controller for the `date()` function and also how to make its route.

Comment: please write more why you need

Comment: you can't just ask! at least show what you tried.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying, perhaps you should read this so you can manage dates better in laravel https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon

Comment: use Carbon extension'

Answer (score 0):

just use date() function or Carbon

Answer (score 0):

Date/Time in Laravel

Package called Carbon can help make dealing with date/time in PHP much easier.

Usage example:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

// get the current time  - 2015-12-19 10:10:54
$current = Carbon::now();
$current = new Carbon();

// get today - 2015-12-19 00:00:00
$today = Carbon::today();

// get yesterday - 2015-12-18 00:00:00
$yesterday = Carbon::yesterday();

// get tomorrow - 2015-12-20 00:00:00
$tomorrow = Carbon::tomorrow();

// parse a specific string - 2016-01-01 00:00:00
$newYear = new Carbon('first day of January 2016');

// set a specific timezone - 2016-01-01 00:00:00
$newYearPST = new Carbon('first day of January 2016', 'America\Pacific');
```

I hope it helps.